# Boxing value type to send it to a method and get the result

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, value-type, boxing, reference-type

I'm curious about how C# behaves when passing value/reference types into a method. I'd like to pass a boxed value type into the method "*AddThree*". The idea is to get in the caller function (*Main*) the result of the operations performed within "*AddThree*".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int age = 3;
    object myBox = age;
    AddThree(myBox);
    // here myBox = 3 but I was expecting to be  = 6
}

private static void AddThree(object age2)
{
    age2 = (int)age2 + 3;
}
```

I've tried this with pure reference types like *string* and I get the same result. If I "wrap" my *int* within a class and I use the "wrap" class in this example it works as I'm expecting, ie, I get myBox = 6. If I modify "AddThree" method signature to pass the parameter by ref, this also returns 6. But, **I don't want to modify the signature or create a wrapper class, I want to just box the value.**

Comment: There's no way to do this without changing the signature since you need `age2` to be a `ref` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to modify the signature or create a wrapper class, I
>   want to just box the value.

Then that will be a problem. Your method passes a boxed `int`, then unboxes it and adds 3 to the local `age2`, which causes another boxing operation, and then throws away the value. De-facto, you're assinging `age2` to two different objects on the heap, they do not point to the same object. 
Without modifying the method signature, this won't be possible.

If you look at the generated IL for `AddThree`, you'll see this clearly:

```
AddThree:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  unbox.any   System.Int32 // unbox age2
IL_0007:  ldc.i4.3    // load 3
IL_0008:  add         // add the two together
IL_0009:  box         System.Int32 // box the result
IL_000E:  starg.s     00 
IL_0010:  ret
```

You unbox the value, add 3 and then box the value again, but you never return it.

To visualize this case further, try returning the newly boxed value from the method (just for the sake of the test), and use `object.ReferenceEquals` to compare them both:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int age = 3;
    object myBox = age;
    var otherBox = AddThree(myBox);
    Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(otherBox, myBox)); // False
}

private static object AddThree(object age2)
{
    age2 = (int)age2 + 3;
    return age2;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Boxed references meant to be immutable. For example, this will not compile (assuming `Point` is a value type):

```
((Point)p).X += 3; // CS0445: Cannot modify the result of an unboxing conversion.
```

As the others said, this line causes a pair of boxing and unboxing operation, which ends up in a new reference:

```
age2 = (int)age2 + 3;
```

So even though a boxed int is actually a reference the line above modifies the object reference as well, so the caller will still see the same content unless the object itself is passed by reference.

However, there are a few ways for dereferencing and changing a boxed value without changing the reference (none of them are recommended, though).

**Solution 1:**

The simplest way is via reflection. This seems a bit silly because the `Int32.m_value` field is the int value itself but this allows you to access the int directly.

```
private static void AddThree(object age2)
{
    FieldInfo intValue = typeof(int).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredField("m_value");
    intValue.SetValue(age2, (int)age2 + 3);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

This is a much bigger hack and involves the use of the mainly undocumented `TypedReference` and the `__makeref()` operator but more or less this is what happens in the background in the first solution:

```
private static unsafe void AddThree(object age2)
{
    // pinning is required to prevent GC relocating the object during the pointer operations
    var objectPinned = GCHandle.Alloc(age2, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    try
    {
        // The __makeref() operator returns a TypedReference.
        // It is basically a pair of pointers for the reference value and type.
        TypedReference objRef = __makeref(age2);

        // Dereference it to access the boxed value like this: objRef.Value->object->boxed content
        // For more details see the memory layout of objects: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/05/26/managed-object-internals-part-1-layout/
        int* rawContent = (int*)*(IntPtr*)*(IntPtr*)&objRef;

        // rawContent now points to the type handle (just another pointer to the method table).
        // The actual instance fields start after these 4 or 8 bytes depending on the pointer size:
        int* boxedInt = rawContent + (IntPtr.Size == 4 ? 1 : 2);
        *boxedInt += 3;
    }
    finally
    {
        objectPinned.Free();
    }
}
```

> ⚠️ *Caution:* Please note that this solution is platform dependent and does not work on Mono because its `TypedReference` implementation is different.

> *Edit:* For some reason the latest Roslyn compiler allows `void* p = (void*)&myBoxedObject` directly, which was [illegal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0208) earlier so using a `TypedReference` is actually no longer needed for this approach.

---

**Update: Solution 3:**

Starting with .NET Core you can use a much simpler and performant trick: the `Unsafe.As<T>` method allows you to reinterpret any object as another reference type. All you need is just a class, whose first field has the same type as your boxed value. And actually you can perfectly use the `StrongBox<T>` type for this purpose as its single `Value` field is public and mutable:

```cs
private static void AddThree(object age2) =>
    Unsafe.As<StrongBox<int>>(age2).Value += 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning a new value to a method parameter not passed by `ref` will not change the original reference.

In your case, `age2` (the method parameter) is a copy of `myBox`. They both reference the same object (the boxed `age`), but assigning to `age2` does not change `myBox`. It simply makes `age2` reference another object.

Actually, it has nothing to do with boxing. It's just how parameters are passed to methods.

Comment: It is about boxing, if param would be int, ref would help here. But boxing creates temporary copy of original int, and modification of this copy will be lost anyway, with and without ref.

Comment: @ISanych The OP wanted `myBox` (the boxed one) to change, not `age` (the `int`) : `// here myBox = 3 but I was expecting to be  = 6`. Passing the parameter as `ref object` would accomplish that.

Comment: you are right, I've missed part that OP wanted boxed value.